# Getting an ORA - 00907 error on the following at ON UPDATE

Tags: database, oracle, constraints, create-table

When implementing my oracle database I receive an ORA-00907 error on line 8 at ON UPDATE. Its complaining about right parenthesis but I don't see this error anywhere. whats my issue?

```
CREATE TABLE Result (
Rid number,
Hid number,
Jid number,
Jweight number(5),
Place number(3),
CONSTRAINT Result_PK PRIMARY KEY(Rid, Hid, Jid),
CONSTRAINT ResultRACE_FK FOREIGN KEY(Rid) REFERENCES Race(Rid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT ResultHORSE_FK FOREIGN KEY(Hid) REFERENCES Horse(Hid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT ResultJOCKEY_FK FOREIGN KEY(Jid) REFERENCES Jockey(Jid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT Jweight_Check CHECK(Jweight > 0 AND Jweight < 116))
```

Comment: Oracle errors come from the Oracle database, not MySQL, so I removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: "ON UPDATE CASCADE" is not supported by Oracle, that's MySQL sintax. It doesn't make sense, anyway...parent keys are not supposed to be updated. https://community.oracle.com/thread/1116280

Comment: Oh I understand. Link was helpful too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle RDBMS does not support `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.